# vim: display relative linenumbers starting with 1

Tags: vim, line-numbers

In vim, I like using relative linenumbers to see how many lines I need to yank, delete, whatever.

However, when using relative linenumbers, the current line is 0, which means, if I want to yank until the line with number 3, I have to type 4yy, which is sort of counterintuitive and is slowing me down.

Is there a way to display relative linenumbers starting with 1 instead of 0?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'd say, work *with* the system. Instead of using a 'repeat' you could modify to use the motion as intended:

<kbd>y3j</kbd> instead of <kbd>4yy</kbd>

You'll notice that the yank command takes a motion. <kbd>yy</kbd> is only there as a shorcut should you not want a motion (by definition it takes the current *line*).

In a sense, doing 4yy is a little bit akward ('4times' take this whole line; You are relying on the fact that the *implict* motion is effectively multiplied by the repeat, it isn't natural since the motion was *implicit*).

On the plus side, you could even combine it: <kbd>4d3j</kbd> (delete 3linesdown 4 times in a row, not a very useful example)

Comment: Learning how to use motions would also enable you to delete/copy 4 lines upwards rapidly (<kbd>y4k</kbd>), instead of having to first move the cursor up four lines and then use <kbd>4yy</kbd> to copy downwards.

Comment: Apparently, the keyboard button tag is not supported in comments. Here is a more legible version - Learning how to use motions would also enable you to delete/copy 4 lines upwards rapidly (`y4k`), instead of having to first move the cursor up four lines and then use `4yy` to copy downwards

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK no... or you can check out `vim` and modify it's source code.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible because the line numbers are relative. First line below current line is rightly numbered 1 and so is the first line above current line.

Agree that you have to do that little math when you are working with commands like `yy`, `dd` etc.